# How do I change an item from a column? (I know some php but I am not an expert)

Tags: php, html, sql

I am a new coder here. I want to edit the column Terminate Reason, I want to fix the spelling mistake of the column item "Resgned" to "Resigned". Can you suggest me what can I do? Please look at the attached image for clear reference. Thank you.

[image: Look at the column "Terminate Reason"]

Comment: This is a sql question more than anything else... please show us your sql schema for the table where this data is sorted.. also what sql system are you using, mysql?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+edit+table+cell+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to update the data:

```
update t
   set termination_reason = 'Resigned'
   where termination_reason = 'Resgned';
```

Note that MySQL now supports check constraints.  So you can validate the data so no bad values can go in:

```
alter table t add constraint check_t_termination_reason
    check ( termination_reason in ('Resigned', . . .) );
```

The `. . .` is for all the other valid values.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. One more thing, where do I update this? In phpmyadmin (database) or in the codes?

Comment: @SaminFarhan it sounds like a one-off administration job to correct the existing data, so it would make sense to just run it on phpmyadmin. You'd only add it to your application if you want users to be able to do this on a regular basis, but that sounds unlikely from your description.